# Historical filtering on mdx query with multiple date dimensions

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have a cube with two date dimension and I need to filter the results of my query like this SQL condition:

```
WHERE fechavalidezdesde <= 2016-01-01
AND (fechavalidezhasta IS NULL OR (fechavalidezhasta > 2016-01-01))
```

I do this filter, but, I failed setting the another condition.

```
WHERE (
    FILTER([Fecha Validez Hasta].Members, 
    isEmpty([Fecha Validez Hasta].CURRENTMEMBER) OR
    [Fecha Validez Hasta].CURRENTMEMBER > [Fecha Validez Hasta].[2016].[2].[17])
)
```

Please, anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: To do this, I suggest reading a book on MDX.

Comment: Thanks Luc. When I decided to do this question, I had five days reading about MDX, but, my english proficiency is not the better and mostly of the documentation is in this language. I appreciate your interest for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely won't work as a condition:

```
[Fecha Validez Hasta].CURRENTMEMBER > [Fecha Validez Hasta].[2016].[2].[17]
```

As it is comparing members, not their values.

This looks valid:

```
FILTER(
  [Fecha Validez Hasta].Members AS S, 
  isEmpty(s.CURRENTMEMBER)
)
```

Does that section work on it's own without the invalid section?

If the above bit is ok maybe the second condition can be added like this as it is comparing two numerical values for the second condition:

```
FILTER(
  [Fecha Validez Hasta].Members AS S, 
  isEmpty(s.CURRENTMEMBER)
  OR
  s.CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_KEY > 20160217
)
```